# Recognize the checkbox checked or not in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I check if a checkbox is checked with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204867/how-do-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery)

I have a following form which opens in light box

```
<form name="adminFormMod" id="adminFormMod" action="index.php" method="post">

<input type="text" name="myname" value="sss"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test" value="tttt"  />
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="updateresults()"/>

</form>
```

On the js page which includes on the above page when i try to check weather the checkbox is checked or not.my following  code is not working

```
alert(document.getElementById('test').checked);
```

the above always alert the fasle

Even with following jquery line of code

```
$('#adminFormMod').find(':input').each(function()
                {
                // alert('idhar');
                  switch(this.type)
                  {
                    case 'text':
                    //alert('text');
                    $(this).val('');
                    break;

                    case 'checkbox':
                    //alert($(this).attr('checked'));
                    if($(this).attr('name')=='test')
                    {
                      alert(this.checked);
                      alert($(this).attr('checked'));
                    }
                    break;

                  }
                }
                );
```

it always alert the false even the checkbox is checked.Please help

Comment: before ask a question , at least do a Google search............ don't put any thing with out a research

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#yourCheckbox').is(':checked')
```

Comment: can i use keyword  (this) instead of #yourcheckbox because there is gone a be multiple checkbox which will create dynamicaly

Comment: It depends what "this" is in your context. If you iterate over a collection with some jQuery selector, then `this` is in most cases the current jQuery element captured by that selector; hence you can do something like `this.is(":checked")` or alternatively if it is the DOM element `$(this).is(":checked")`. But in your case you might also want to try capturing all checked inputs with some more generic selector like `$("input:checked").each(function...`

Comment: thank you for your answers and comments but i think there is some problem because as i said my form is opening in lightbox so the code is not giving the right result.what i should i do then?please help

Answer (score 2):

probably a duplicate of: [How do I check if a checkbox is checked with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204867/how-do-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery)

checked being a property and not an attribute you need to write the code slightly differently:

```
$('#checkbox').is(":checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

  var n = $("input:checked").length;
if(n>0)
{
alert('checked');
}

}

</script>
```

http://oops-solution.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

some others ways are

```
// First way 
$('#checkBox').attr('checked'); 

// Second way 
$('#edit-checkbox-id').is(':checked'); 

// Third way for jQuery 1.2
$("input[@type=checkbox][@checked]").each( 
    function() { 
       // Insert code here 
    } 
);
```

http://oops-solution.blogspot.com/